# Connecting to a remote machine with a public key using Fugu

Tags: ssh, aws, scp

How do I connect to a remote server with a public key using [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/)? I'm using Amazon EC2, so I have `.pem` public key, but I'm totally new to Fugu and I can't see any form or input for the public key. In the "connect to" text input shall I enter in my public DNS?

Answer (score 3):

Note: I found entering `-i ~/PATH/TO/ec2-keypair.pem` didn't work for me, but another workaround in the same field worked.

In the "Advanced SFTP Options", in the same Additional SSH Options dialogue enter:

> `-oIdentityFile=~/PATH/TO/ec2-keypair.pem`

So, for example, if your EC2 instance looks like

> `root@ec2-123-45-678-910.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

with your key being at the root and named

> `ec2-keypair.pem`

then the relevant input is:

> Connect to: `ec2-123-45-678-910.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
>
> Username: `root`
>
> Additional SSH options: `-oIdentityFile=~/ec2-keypair.pem`

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

Fugu is really just a graphical front-end to the built-in ssh/sftp commands you could use in Terminal.  I found a nice write-up for getting started with EC2 for MacOSX users by Robert Sosinski: [Starting Amazon EC2 with MacOSX](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/01/26/starting-amazon-ec2-with-mac-os-x/)

Note that he walks you through some Terminal commands, including generating a new ssh keypair to connect to your chosen EC2 image.  When you get that ready and can successfully connect to your EC2 server via ssh in Terminal, then you can use Fugu for further file transfers.

In the main Fugu window, if you expand "Advanced SFTP Options", you'll see a field where you can enter Additional SSH options.  You could enter something like:
`-i ~/.ec2/ec2-keypair`
to indicate the appropriate ssh key to use.  And in the example he gives, you would connect to `root@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.